Cannot run .command file stored on iCloud?
I have a .command file stored on iCloud. When I double click it, the terminal gives:
find: /Users/(my_name)/Library\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/my_command.command: No such file or directory
What's wrong with it?
